# Using rails localization I18n on client side

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n

Is it possible, to get all localization features of rails app, when using client side view rendering?

Any suggestion about how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`i18n-js`](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) gem.....